# Access view from Runnable cause memory leak?

Tags: android, memory-leaks

This is a piece of code from the docs of android:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            final Bitmap bitmap =
                    loadImageFromNetwork("http://example.com/image.png");
            mImageView.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}
```

My question is why it is ok to use `mImageView` inside the `Runnable`, I mean when we run this piece of code the `mImageView` might not be existed so this is a memory leak, am i right? If so, why people do that kind of thinks like reference a `View` inside a `Runnable`.

Comment: You're right that it is a memory leak. The question is "why" better to ask who wrote this snippet

Comment: ok, it is just weird that a lot of android programs i see online contain something like this code.